# JSONexception while using json parser android java

Tags: java, android, json

i can't show my search result to webview on my app because error JSONexception, this my json:

```
"items":[
            {
            "kind":"customsearch#result",
            "title":"how  to make android app - Tholabul Ilmi",
            "htmlTitle":"how to make \u003cb\u003eAndroid\u003c/b\u003e app - Tholabul ilmi",
            "link":"http://T*****.com/2014/11/create-android-app.html",
            "displayLink":"T****.com",
            "snippet":"11 Nov 2014 ... You can get completed source like video demo, source code, tutorials on my github ...",
            "cacheId":"OTC6MiDeHu8J",
            "pagemap":
                {
                "metatags":[
                                {
                                    "viewport":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
                                }
                            ],
                "hcard":[
                                {
                                    "fn":"Tholabul Ilmi"
                                }
                        ]
            }
},
```

and on my app project i have 2 file activity_main.xml (i insert web view on there) and this my java code.

```
 private String ParseResult(String json) throws JSONException{
        String parsedResult = "";
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONObject jsonObject_responseData = jsonObject.getJSONObject("items");
        JSONArray jsonArray_results = jsonObject_responseData.getJSONArray("");

        parsedResult += "Google Search APIs (JSON) for : <b>" + search_item + "</b><br/>";
        parsedResult += "Number of results returned = <b>" + jsonArray_results.length() + "</b><br/><br/>";

        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray_results.length(); i++){

            JSONObject jsonObject_i = jsonArray_results.getJSONObject(i);

            String iTitle = jsonObject_i.getString("title");
            String iContent = jsonObject_i.getString("snippet");
            String iUrl = jsonObject_i.getString("link");

            parsedResult += "<a href='" + iUrl + "'>" + iTitle + "</a><br/>";
            parsedResult += iContent + "<br/><br/>";
        }

        return parsedResult;
    }
```

i confused, what must i fill on getJSONArray and how make it works for displaying something i searched on myweb blogs, i use google custom search and on in app when user type text and click search it will be display result about it of my blogs. I want to create widget search like a google search widget.

Comment: Are you sure your JSON is properly structured? It doesn't seem to be syntactically correct. Second, what is the json that you are receiving at the ParseJson method? Third, what is the stacktrace that you are seeing? And fourth, check out Java naming standards.

Comment: @prabugp offcourse sir, you can try create google custom search for your blogs on https://www.google.com/cse/ i'm sure you can api json like it, this my java full code http://pastebin.com/GFxLCY3g on stackrace i see no value for item

Comment: your JSON is not valid JSON aka it is not JSON

Comment: Oke guys, this my completed json http://pastebin.com/mBrZ116L

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, your JSON String is not valid.

here is the valid string...
try using valid JSON String...

You can check JSON validation on this site:

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

```
{"items":[
{
"kind":"customsearch#result",
"title":"how  to make android app - Tholabul Ilmi",
"htmlTitle":"how to make \u003cb\u003eAndroid\u003c/b\u003e app - Tholabul ilmi",
"link":"http://T*****.com/2014/11/create-android-app.html",
"displayLink":"T****.com",
"snippet":"11 Nov 2014 ... You can get completed source like video demo, source code, tutorials on my github ...",
"cacheId":"OTC6MiDeHu8J",
"pagemap":{
"metatags":[
{
"viewport":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
}
],
"hcard":[
{
"fn":"Tholabul Ilmi"
}
]
}
}]}
```